# List active forum threads

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_content = 'thread' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 65");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 echo "$row['post_contentID']";
}
```

I'm want to list forum threads that there has recently been posts posted in.
The "problem" is that it lists the same thread more than once. If I have posted in a thread like 5 times it will show all the 5 times I just want it to show it 1 time...this is hard to explain when your english is not so wide...

Like they have on this site https://stackoverflow.com/?sort=active You know if i would answer a question that is in the bottom, it will show on the top for me it shows all posts that has been posted in the thread.

Thanks
Piotr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE post_content = 'thread'
GROUP BY post_contentID
ORDER BY MAX(post_date) DESC
LIMIT 65
```

Note that I'm assuming that "post_contentID" is the thread id, if it's not, you need to use the thread id in the GROUP BY clause instead.